# Automorphism group of a product of two simplices

Tags: combinatorics, automorphism-group, simplicial-complex

Is there a description of the group of automorphisms of a product of two simplices depending on the dimension of the simplices?

By automorphisms, I mean simplicial automorphisms of a simplicial complex on $\Delta^p\times \Delta^q$. The simplicial structure on the product is introduced in the standard minimal manner described, for instance, in the second part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113825/402997).